# German words list sorted by frequency

Tags: big-list

I am looking for something similar to this list: https://www.wordfrequency.info/samples.asp
It is a list of about 5000 lemmas sorted by their frequency. Where can I find this type of high-quality list of German words?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question does not require a list that is available for free, here is my suggestion: [*A Frequency Dictionary of German: Core Vocabulary for Learners*](https://www.routledge.com/A-Frequency-Dictionary-of-German-Core-Vocabulary-for-Learners/Tschirner-Mohring/p/book/9781138659780) by Erwin Tschirner and Jupp Möhring (second edition, Routledge, 2020). According to the publisher, the book

> contains the 5,000 most commonly used words of German today, occurring in a 20-million-word corpus (compared to a 4.2-million-word corpus in the first edition). The basis of the frequency list is a significantly extended version of the Herder/BYU Corpus of Contemporary German. The Dictionary contains spoken and written German, and represents different genres, text types, registers, styles, and also regional varieties.